# Setting Image Size inside Canvas with JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**Hello Everyone, 

So there is a HTML Canvas with photo editing tool. Which looks like this -**

[image]

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 col-sm-12" id="mainDiv">
  <div 
    id="canvas1Div" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    title="" 
    data-original-title="Image Processing Area"
  >
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="564" height="488"> </canvas>
  </div>
  <div
    id="canvasDiv" 
    data-toggle="tooltip" 
    data-original-title="" 
    title="" 
    style="border: 0px;"
  >
    <canvas id="canvas3" width="188" height="240"> </canvas>
    <canvas
      id="canvas4" 
      width="188" 
      height="240" 
      style="width: 188px; height: 240px;"
    > </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

**So could it be possilbe with JavaScript that the photo I choose can fit to the center part of the canvas (colorfull borders) by executing it on the console of the browser? 

Thank you.**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the image on the canvas using this approach:

```js
ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

- `sx`, `sy`, `sWidth` & `sHeight` are used for cropping the image
- `dx`, `dy`, `dWidth` & `dHeight` are used for positioning the image within the canvas. These arguments should correlate with your desired rect position and size.

To learn more on this checkout this link: [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)

**Edit**

Use the native [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) class to import any image from your pc:

```js
const image = new Image(width, height);

// render image on canvas when it‘s done loading
image.onload = () => ctx.drawImage(image, …);

// load the image
image.src = './path/to/image.png';
```

Comment: I am browsing the image from the pc. What should I use in place of "image" variable?